# Is there a compendium of terse-but-devastating attempted refutations of religion?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-religion

I hear many arguments against religion in general, as well as against particular religions. Most of these arguments fall far short of being devastating; however, every so often I encounter an argument that is **short**, **sweet**, and very very **strong.** I'm interested in hearing/reading more such arguments. In particular, they should be:

- **Terse**; for example, less than half a page long each; some might be only a few sentences.
- **Logical**; for example, breaking into cases is good.
- **Philosophically careful**; even a trained philosopher should have difficulty seeing any flaws in the argument, and the argument should be immune to terse rebuttals.
- **Devastating if correct**; the conclusion of the argument should be such that if you accept the argument, then there is no scope for believing in that particular religion anymore (if it argues against a particular religion) or that class of religions (if it argues against a whole class of religions).

> **Question.** I'd like to read, purchase or otherwise have access to a compendium of these kinds of terse-but-devastating attempted refutations of religion(s). Does such a resource exist?

A bit of housekeeping:

- I originally provided an example of the kind of argument I was looking for, but it was distracting people from the actual question, so I removed it. Therefore, I will not provide readers with any examples of the kind of arguments I'm looking for.
- On the other hand, will happily add clarification as to what I mean by certain terms such as "religion," so long as I'm provided with a concrete context in which ambiguity in these terms becomes problematic to answering the question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21209/discussion-on-question-by-goblin-is-there-a-compendium-of-terse-but-devastating).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think books are always a good go-to for what you are looking for, although some authors are more terse than others. Sam Harris I would say has the most "straight to the point" writing style, with a dash of wit thrown in as well. His book, [*Letter to a Christian Nation*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0307278778) is about 100 small-sized/large font pages and is probably a good start for what you are looking for. He also wrote [*The End of Faith*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393327655) which is a bit longer, and goes into a bit more depth. Richard Dawkins is a bit more verbose, but he's also a good source of common arguments against god.

If you are looking for website, the general starting place might be the wikipedia page for this topic: [Arguments againstthe existence of God](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existence_of_God#Arguments_against_the_existence_of_God). Mostly they seem to focus on the Abrahamic God, so keep that in mind if you are looking for arguments against religions that might not fall under that umbrella.

There's also a few other website that list some of the major arguments, such as [The Secular Web](http://infidels.org/library/modern/nontheism/atheism/arguments.html) and a user-generated, forum-based verion which can be found at [nairaland.com](http://www.nairaland.com/1150005/library-best-40-atheist-arguments).

Comment: I really appreciate that your answer makes an effort to focus on the actual question asked. I already feel a little happier. Thank you, and +1.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with arguing against religion is that [everyone's view of god is different](http://wiki.ironchariots.org/index.php?title=Arguments_against_the_existence_of_god).  In addition, the most logically sound argument can be (and often is) denied by one not willing to listen (or one suspect of the logic used to arrive at that conclusion).

If you are seeking "devastating" arguments against religion, you must hammer out exactly what kind of attributes the opponent claims their particular brand of god has.  Is he an all knowing god?  All powerful?  Perfectly moral?  These are things that can be argued against, but you should not assume that every Christian (for example) is claiming all of these things are true.  Not all Christians even believe the Bible is [entirely accurate](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7648/is-it-possible-for-the-bible-to-contain-errors).

[An awesome argument against a perfectly moral god](http://wiki.ironchariots.org/index.php?title=Moral_argument) falls flat against someone okay with their god not being perfectly moral in the first place.

All that being said, I find a good resource for researching specific religious claims and the refutations thereof to be [the Iron Chariot's Wiki](http://wiki.ironchariots.org/index.php?title=Arguments_against_the_existence_of_god).  It's run by an Atheist group of out Austin, TX that does a lot of counter-apologetics work.

Comment: Thanks, the Iron Chariots wiki looks useful (+1). As for not all Christians believing that the Bible is entirely accurate; well, if an all-powerful God has an all-important message for us, and if that message *is* the bible (a collection of propositions that most Christians agree upon), then he would make sure that it does indeed remain entirely accurate. So in regards to most brands of Christianity, we may assume [wlog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) that the bible is 100% accurate. I think people give up way too easily on these things.

Comment: I am glad it looks helpful, though I disagree with your claim that you can assume the Bible is 100% accurate "without loss of generality" (I like that phrase, fyi).  Evidence based on such assumptions sound nice in isolation, but do not stand up to debate or textual interpretation by a "believer."  Disproving a religious passage as being literally true does very little against common, non-literal  interpretations (such as [midrash, or simply being an artifact of historical culture](http://www.religioustolerance.org/chr_inte1.htm)).

Comment: Suppose there was an all-powerful deity who cares very deeply about our behaviour, and has a very specific message for us, which is encoded in the bible. Then he would not allow artefacts of historical culture to corrupt this message, since our very salvation depends on that message. And if there was ambiguity as to how literally this message was to be translated, he would immediately act to remove this ambiguity. In fact, I imagine he would beam his will directly into our brains, in words (vision etc.) custom designed to maximize understanding, thereby giving us maximum freedom...

Comment: ...in so far as accepting or rejecting his will. In any event, there would certainly be minimum scope for ambiguity in the meanings of His words, since the only reason for ambiguity is our own limited intelligence. But no sane person would argue that the bible is at the absolute minimum level of ambiguity that is possible given our human limitations, nor that God immediately acts to remove ambiguity whenever it exists, nor that he clearly and unambiguously beams his will into into our heads, nor that there is really any good evidence for belief in Christianity specifically.

Comment: In summary, I think that no matter how we try to slice and dice this cake, Christianity simply doesn't agree with what is actually observed. I'm having fun, by the way.

Comment: Which Bible are your referring to? The original Greek or the heavily edited multi reinterpreted English?

Comment: @goblin: the standard counterargument is that you are making quite a lot of assumptions about how a superior being *should* act or *may* act.  Most religions consider such phrasings very dangerous; some consider them heretical.  Using them in the wrong situation may do *far* more damage than just letting the religious person be, in peace.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda, it shouldn't matter. If it was God's word, and if our very salvation depends on his word being preserved uncorrupted by translation, then he'd protect it from corruption.

Comment: @CortAmmon, I cannot see any assumptions I'm making that are genuinely controversial among Christians. I'm assuming that God has an important message for us, and that that message is for some reason written in the bible. Frankly, if a Christian doesn't believe one or both of these propositions, then I see no claims that deserve to be questioned or opposed. What other assumptions am I making?

Comment: @goblin This isn't the place for a debate --we have [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21094/discussion-between-goblin-and-demosthene) for that, as you seem to be aware.

Comment: @CortAmmon, also, most Christians would agree: "God would never punish someone for believing in Him." In agreeing, they are admitting to believing that they're able predict how a superior being should or may act. In fact, many Christian beliefs are predicated on the idea that we can predict God's behavior; for instance, belief in the efficacy of prayer implies belief in the ability to influence the decision making of God.

Comment: @ChrisSunami, for some reason, the option to move this discussion to chat isn't appearing for me.

Comment: @goblin Unfortunately, that option only appears when the algorithm thinks it is needed, for reasons that are obscure to me.  However, you can post in one of the existing chat rooms based on this post.  If you @ the person you are referencing, it should appear in their inbox.

Comment: @goblin.  This comment does belong in chat, but I'm hoping that by posting it as a comment, it will give people the link to move all of this to chat: "God would never punish someone for believing in Him" is in direct contradiction with the story of Job if you consider God responsible for everything (including the acts of Satan).

Comment: @CortAmmon, I have to read the story of Job before I can comment. So if we just keep writing comments here, will a button eventually appear that moves everything to chat?

Comment: @goblin: That is my experience.  Apparently moderators also have the ability to move this to chat, so we could also just wait for one of them to come along.  There is some value in quiet.  While some initial debates, like we've had, tend to be productive, it is *terribly* easy for it to accidentally devolve into attacks on a religion, which do not belong on this stack exchange, on no fault of either party.  I would recommend adjourning while we are still civil and neither of us have unintentionally incited a third party in our discourse.

Answer (score 2):

There are no compendia about the refutation of religion(s) since 'religion' is a factual cultural institution present in all human societies. I believe you are referring to the refutation of God(s), in which case I would recommend you Wikipedia.

If you really meant religion(s) as in Catholicism, Judaism, Buddhism, ... then I suggest you Michel Onfray, Richard Dawkins and Lawrence Krauss who refute religion(s) from an atheistic perspective. But then again, they don't refute the existence of religions, they refute their desirability.

FYI the term 'religion' does not necessarily imply the term 'god': there are religions without gods, such as Buddhism.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you mean by "factual cultural institution"? Do you just mean that it is a fact that religion permeates all human societies, or are you saying something else?

Comment: Yes, I mean religions have existed as long as humans have and still permeates most human societies (Western countries are less and less religious though).

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely obvious what you're asking for, because it's not clear what you mean by 'arguments against religion in general'. Are you looking for arguments against religious institutions? Or against the belief systems endorsed by those institutions? Or against a particular religion's conception of God? An argument against one of those isn't necessarily an argument against any of the others.

If you're looking for arguments concerning the existence of God, then the best place to start is the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy. You can access it online. Here are some relevant articles:

http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ontological-arguments/

http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/teleological-arguments/

Note that these are survey articles: they outline the issues and give you a high-level view of the issues. So they may not be as terse as you would like. That said, it is not obvious that terse philosophy is good philosophy. Either way, the above are worth the read.

Comment: I think that terse refutations are usually the strongest. Think about it mathematically; to refute a conjecture, you only need a single, well-chosen counterexample. You do not need a big, complicated, elaborate theory. But lets just be 100% clear; I'm not claiming that *all* philosophy should be terse, just that the best **refutations**, *usually* are.

Answer (score 0):

I would say apophatic theology does a fairly good job of demolishing fanciful definitions of God upon which some religions base their teachings.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophatic_theology#Apophatic_description_of_God

> Negative theology has a place in the Western Christian tradition as
>   well, although it is definitely much more of a counter-current to the
>   prevailing positive or cataphatic traditions central to Western
>   Christianity. For example, theologians like Meister Eckhart and St.
>   John of the Cross (San Juan de la Cruz), mentioned above, exemplify
>   some aspects of or tendencies towards the apophatic tradition in the
>   West. The medieval work, The Cloud of Unknowing and St. John's Dark
>   Night of the Soul are particularly well known in the West.

There is also some similarity with this in Buddhism, in the [Diamond Sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_Sutra):

> After these words, the venerable Subhûti spoke thus to Bhagavat: 'O
>   Bhagavat, how is this treatise of the Law called, and how can I learn
>   it?' After this, Bhagavat spoke thus to the venerable Subhûti: 'This
>   treatise of the Law, O Subhûti, is called the Pragñâ-pâramitâ
>   (Transcendent wisdom), and you should learn it by that name. And why?
>   Because, O Subhûti, what was preached by the Tathâgata as the
>   Pragñâ-pâramitâ, that was preached by the Tathâgata as no-Pâramitâ.
>   Therefore it is called the Pragñâ-pâramitâ.
>
> 'Then, what do you think, O Subhûti, is there anything (dharma) that
>   was preached by the Tathâgata?' Subhûti said: 'Not indeed, O Bhagvat,
>   there is not anything that was preached by the Tathâgata.'

source: http://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/sbe49/sbe4929.htm

Answer (score 0):

You will easily devastate poorly-founded justifications for the existence of God but you will always struggle to devastate arguments such as [these](http://web.mnstate.edu/gracyk/courses/web%20publishing/aquinasFiveWays_ArgumentAnalysis.htm).

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer (it doesn't attempt to answer the question asked, and furthermore it consists of essentially a link to elsewhere, which is a no-no on SE). Also, in case you aren't aware, there exist numerous credible refutations of Aquinas.

Comment: @DanBron The question asks if there exists a list, it does not ask for a list to be provided.  My answer argues that there does not exist a list which will ever satisfy the OP's criteria for refutation of *theism*, which I think is his intended meaning; although technically many atheists are religiously atheist if we focus on "religious" to mean *as a matter of doctrine*; or *taking something to be true in the absence of proof thereof.* Therefore this is the only answer which does indeed answer the question.

Comment: @RobertFrost, "proof" is far too high of a standard; we never truly have proof of anything. The problem with that definition of "religious" is that every belief is religious according to your proposed definition.

Comment: @goblin we can easily have proof of God, especially since God is so badly defined. To an omnitheist the existence of God is as straightforward a fact as the existence of the universe.

Comment: @RobertFrost, I agree with the general point about definitions, and I want to concede the point you're trying to make about omnitheism, but I'm not sold. You can't mathematically prove that the universe exists through logic alone, because its an empirical statement that has no clear analog in the world of mathematics. So you have to rely on softer arguments e.g. "I think, therefore I am," and such arguments, being soft, fall far short of genuine proof in my opinion. In fact, even full-blown mathematical proof isn't really proof, since it presupposes that we're not mistaken about e.g. whether..

Comment: ...an inference rule was applied correctly. So, even if you want to talk about omnitheism, it's still the case that genuine proof is too high of a standard to set. I maintain that human beings never genuinely prove anything, not even in mathematics, because there's always room for error.

Comment: @goblin I accept we can't prove the universe exists with logic, but there comes a point where we have to take something's truth as self-evident. When the counterargument to some statement reduces to it only exists insofar as we can say the universe exists then we've achieved the strongest  degree of proof there is in my world. As for the existence of God, moving out of logic and into opinion I see a Universe which is clearly alive and has a 'personal' character in the sense that a 'personal' god does so the existence of God is, for me, self-evident and I require faith nor religion to believe.

Comment: @RobertFrost, "but there comes a point where we have to take something's truth as self-evident." I agree, but that doesn't make its truth *proven.* My point was that this is altogether the wrong word; if proof is the dividing line that separates religious claims from irreligious claims, then even the statement "the universe exists" is a form of religion, no matter how self-evident its truth is. As for this 'personal' business, all I can say is that it doesn't really resonate with me. I don't really understand what you mean by all that.

Comment: @goblin I mean a personal god as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_god

Comment: @RobertFrost, the vast majority of the universe is nearly-empty space, with perhaps the occasional asteroid or cancer-causing gamma ray to keep the lonely interstellar traveler company. Even if there's other life-bearing planets out there, the small pockets of life are grossly outweighed by the cold desert of unlivable void that constitutes the vast majority of our universe. So you perhaps understand why this talk of a universe that is "self-evidently alive" makes me cringe inside. As for a universe with a "personal" character, I don't get it. I'm afraid you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: @goblin if you look within your body the vast majority is nearly-empty space, with the perhaps occasional particle. In fact proportionally the distance from proton to electron in the average hydrogen atom is around 300 times the distance from Sun to the Earth. And I'm sure your protons, electrons and other particles are no more "personal" than your asteroids and gamma rays. So by your argument, you are not "personal".

Comment: @RobertFrost, I agree. I'm not "personal". By the way, I didn't make an argument. I just explained why I find that kind of talk cringeworthy. If you want to persuade people to engage with your position in a less superficial way, you'll have to find ways of expressing your position that don't make other people cringe inside. Perhaps try starting a blog where you can express a refined version of your position, and then redirect people there.